# Delphi XE2 64 bit client connection to Firebird 2.5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a DelphiXE2 client running against a Firebird 2.5 32bit session.

My development environment is Windows 7 64bit, and I use the InterBase client components.

Everything works fine as long as I compile the project 32bit.

The project compiles fine to 64bit - very pleased :-) - but then I get a "connection rejected by remote interface" error on login - not pleased :-(

I have ensured to remove all gds32.dll and I have installed Firebird 2.5 client 32bit fbclient.dll. The fbclient.dll is copied to the SysWOW64 directory.

What can be causing this reject?

Comment: why do u say gds32.dll ? that should be fbclient.dll ! and what library (components) do you use to connect the database in Delphi code ?

Answer (score 4):

A requirement of the system is:

**All the libraries loaded by a executable must be of the same bitness**, this means you must load 64 bit dll's on a 64 bit process and 32 bit dll's on a 32 bit process.

Take a look at the **No Mixed 64-Bit/32-Bit Processes** entry in [List of limitations in 64-Bit Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423)

This applies to the Firebird client also. In order to successfully connect to your Firebird database from a 64 bit process you **must install the 64 bit client of Firebird**.

A machine may have both 32 bit and 64 bit clients installed, since they reside in different folders, the dll's can and usually have the same name.

This doesn't affect the ability to connect to 32 or 64 bit servers. In other words, this is not about the Firebird Server, all is about the Firebird Client.

Comment: I still get the same "connection rejected by remote interface" with the 64bit fbclient.dll. I have also tried to copy the dll to the application folder of the project, still the same error?

Comment: are you sure your application is using the fbClient at all? If you're using IBX, which I don't since ages, your application is maybe tied to the Interbase client library: gds32.dll.

Comment: I have deleted all gds32.dll. I have also tried the option in the Firebird installation, that installs the fbclient.dll as gds32.dll. Nothing seems to help. Are any of you developpers running a 64bit client with Interbase components?

Comment: The Firebird.log at the server lists the error as "connection rejected for ADMINISTRATOR" -1.-1  no matter which user I log in as from the 64bit client???